# Assign value of a button for each row

Tags: php

I am trying to use php and I am really new to it.

I create one page that (with a php code) send the info to the database and one page that display the info from the databse.

My question is: Lets say I am going to input 10 info , but I am displaying just 5 of them, how can I display the rest of the info clicking to a button for each row?

Do I have to assign to the button a value? I cant understand how I can relate the button to the row.

Basically for each row I want to display the rest of the info of that specific row clicking on that specific button.

Any help will be appricciate. thanks

----- script that insert the info in the db-----

```
<?php

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
$mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['mail']);
$number = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['number']);
$device = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['device']);
$model = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['model']);
$problem = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['problem']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO cj (name, mail, number, device, model, problem) VALUES ('$name', '$mail', '$number', '$device', '$model', '$problem')";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        // if query fails stop script and echo error
    if( $result === false)
    {echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        exit;
    }        
    header("location:add-customer.php?message=A job and customer has been added to the database");

    exit;
        echo "You'll never see this";
    ?>
```

----------- page that shows the info ------

```
     <?php
$sql = "SELECT * from "database name"";
    echo "
<table class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>";
/* Get field information for all columns */

    echo "<form action='' method=post>";
    echo "<tr class='info'>

                 <input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['id'] . ">
                <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $row['device'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $row['problem'] . "</td>
                <td>

            </td>        

                <td> 
                <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' value= " . $row['id'] . " >  Info</a></form></td>

           </tr>"; 
    echo "</form>";


}
echo "
    </tbody>

</table>";

?>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Customer Information</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

       <?php
include("../includes/connection.php");
if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}
$sql = "SELECT name,mail,number from databasename WHERE **???**;


if (!$result = $link->query($sql)) {

    die('There was an error running the query [' . $link->error . ']');
}
echo "
<table class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>";
/* Get field information for all columns */
while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
    echo "
        <th>" . $finfo->name . "</th>";
}
echo "
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr class='info'>

                <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['mail'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>

    </tr>";

...
```

Comment: So is the button taking the user to a "details" page where he can see more info about the row, or more like an "expand" button where the content is shown on click?

Comment: you'll need to show your code because i have no idea what a quantifiable "info" is in this context

Comment: @yes the button is taking to a modal pop up which is displaying more info about the same row the button has been clicked. That is why I think there should be assigned a value to the button same as the row id for exemple....but i am not sure

Comment: Then you'll need modals with an id ex: row-1, and a button with a data attribute equal to the modal id. When a button is clicked you show that modal.

Comment: I update with some code. Lets say my table has field: device, model, problem and name , mail, number. Instead of diplaying eveything I want to show for each row the field "name, mail, numner" and with a button (for each row), diplay name, mail and number

Comment: Learn AJAX. Just Advice.

Comment: @ PHPglue, so with AJAX I can achive what I described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using ajax:

here is the code: (an ajax call to a third php page which fixed my problem)

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.get_info').click(function(){
        var job_id = $(this).parent().siblings('input[name=hidden]').val();
        $.ajax({
          url: 'THIRDPAGE.php',
          data: 'job_id=' + job_id,
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(data){
            // console.log(data);
            $('.info_data').html(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

For the oone that is getting here just comment and I can explain better what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to datatabase and get all 10 info with PHP. But show only 5 info. Put a button there, and use Javascript or Jquery to show other rows. (Onclick event)

Comment: So I should put for each row an Onclick event that shows info about that specific row? Sounds ok, but I cannot code this for each row, What if I am gonna have 300 row....